# Replicating Teamviewers Firewall Busting Capabilties for Standard Services

Tags: ssh, tunnel, teamviewer

I love Teamviewers capability to bust through firewalls and gain access to a computer no matter where that computer is located. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this same level of network-fu with standard services like ssh. For example, being able to ssh into a box regardless of that computers location and regardless of any firewalls it might be behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need a trusted 3rd party site that acts as a broker.

Synology (the NAS manufacturer) for example, provides such a tool so that you can access your NAS from anywhere.